# AIX How to import CA certificate

Tags: aix, openssl, certificates

I need to import my company's CA certificate to AIX6. I copied .crt file to `/var/ssl/certs` and `/opt/freeware/etc/ssl/certs/` where all CA certificates are located, but I it's not enough. How should I register new certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution on http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml

Check where is located openssl directory:

```
# openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/var/ssl"
```

Copy .crt file to openssl cert directory (OPENSSLDIR/certs):

```
# cp CA.crt /var/ssl/certs/CA.crt
```

OpenSSL looks up certificates by using their hashes. Certificate hash can be calculated using command:

```
# openssl x509 -noout -hash -in /var/ssl/certs/CA.crt
```

Create symbolic link with hash to original certificate in OpenSSL certificate directory:

```
# cd /var/ssl/certs
# ln -s CA.crt `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in CA.crt`.0
```

Validate if certificate is installed correctly by trying to connect to website which uses it:

```
# openssl s_client -connect <server>:port
```